# How to remove all items from jComboBox except index 0(zero)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have `jComboBox` and I want to refresh `jComboBox` by using `jComboBox.removeAllItems()`. But it removes all items available on `jComboBox` including `Select` which is default value. I want to keep `Select` value always on jComboBox.

**Note:** I search on internet but not find exact solution what I wanted so  asked.

Thanks.

Comment: save the value to a temp, remove all items, insert the saved value back?

Comment: I do not understand will you please elaborate.

Comment: save the value you want to keep to a temporary variable, delete all CB items, insert the value you saved back to the CB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what the value at `0 index` is supposed to be. You could just perform `jComboBox.removeAllItems()` and then add `Select` back.

Comment: After adding the value `Select` what are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually Now value is not changing when I select to Item. I will check my code again.

Answer (score 1):

```
JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>();

String tmp = cb.getItemAt(0);
cb.removeAll();
cb.addItem(tmp);
```

Where 0 is the index you want to save.